# A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Tags: c#, plugins, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, admob

I am trying to develop a windows phone plugin for unity3d to show admob ads. I am new to Windows Phone. I followed the steps from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/wp8-plugins-guide-csharp.html). My code for windows phone class library class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GoogleAds;

namespace UnityPluginForWindowsPhone
{
     /**
     * this class belongs to windows phone class library.
     **/
    public class TAdmob
    {
        private static string interstitialAdUnitId;
        private static InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

        public static void InitInterstitialAd(string adUnitId)
        {
            interstitialAdUnitId = adUnitId;
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);           
        }

        public static void ShowInterstitialAd()
        {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
            interstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnInterstitialAdRecieved;
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);            
        }

        private static void OnInterstitialAdRecieved(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
        {
            interstitialAd.ShowAd();
        }

        public static string GetString()
        {
            return "Hello, Not a device";
        }
    }
}
```

and my windows class library class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace UnityPluginForWindowsPhone
{
    /**
     * this class belongs to windows class library which is used for the unity editor.
     **/
    public class TAdmob
    {

        public static void InitInterstitialAd(string adUnitId)
        {

        }

        public static void ShowInterstitialAd()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and I am getting following message in the log:

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\UnityPluginTestForWindowsPhone.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\WinRTBridge.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\BridgeInterface.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\UnityPlayer.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Build from '' branch, version is '4.3.4f1 (e444f76e01cd)' (Release build).

Physical memory: 907 MB, commited memory limit: 380 MB.

PlayerConnection initialized from C:/Data/Programs/{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}/Install/Data (debug = 0)

PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55344

Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.0.114 [Port] 55344 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 352403036 [EditorId] 599262348 [Version] 1048832 [Id] WP8Player(192.168.0.114) [Debug] 0" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...

Direct3D:

    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 9.3]

    Renderer: Qualcomm Adreno 305 (WDDM v1.2) (ID=0x30303330)

    Vendor:   Qualcomm

    VRAM:     98 MB

Initialize engine version: 4.3.4f1 (e444f76e01cd)

'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\UnityEngine.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\UnityEngineProxy.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\Assembly-CSharp.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\GoogleAds.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\UnityPluginForWindowsPhone.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{857FF137-25B1-462A-BC86-829A1236A776}\Install\UnityEngineDelegates.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Exception: Invalid cross-thread access.
Type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Module: System.Windows
InnerException: <No Data>
AdditionalInfo:Invoking AdButton::OnMouseUpAsButton method with argument count: 0
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MessageBox_ShowCore(String messageBoxText, String caption, UInt32 type)
   at System.Windows.MessageBox.ShowCore(String messageBoxText, String caption, MessageBoxButton button)
   at System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(String messageBoxText)
   at UnityPluginForWindowsPhone.TAdmob.ShowInterstitialAd()
   at AdButton.OnMouseUpAsButton()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] , Int32 )
   at WinRTBridge.MethodTools.InvokeMethod(Object instance, Int32 methodIndex, Object[] args)

(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/Runtime/Scripting/WinRTUtility.cpp Line: 65)
```

I tried to find the file that can't be access using Process Monitor, and find this. Though Can't find what it means. the out put screenshot is given below:
[image: output from process monitor]

I can't figure out what to do. Can anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: the problem is the `FileNotFoundException`, you can use **Sysinternals Process Monitor** to see the IO calls (filter by process name, otherwise you'll get thousands of calls), so you can check which file is being called and have a notion of where in the code the error is happening.

Comment: got process monitor downloaded. but I am getting thousands of calls. don't get how to filter the calls by process name. any suggestion, please? @Roberto

Comment: go to Filter (CTRL+L) and add rules, like "Process Name is" + the name of your process (default name is *Template.exe*). Also "Path contains" + some string that you know is part of the path of the file you are trying to access.

Comment: got some new errors, edited the question.

Comment: added the output of process monitor. but can't understand what it means. @Roberto

Comment: These are all calls to IO in your computer. See the result column? Look for the failed read attempts, probably those "NAME NOT FOUND" results - but do this when the game crashes. With this you'll find out which file name it was trying to access. With the file name is easier for you to look in the game code and see where it's failing. I work with other people's projects everyday and that's the best method I have to find where the code is failing and why when IO errors happen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following permissions checked: "ID_CAP_NETWORKING, ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT, ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK and ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO"